# CSS block not working on jekyll dropdown navbar

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I've been following w3schools and [this other website](https://mycyberuniverse.com/web/jekyll-bootstrap-dynamic-navigation-highlighting-active-element.html) to build a navbar in jekyll using frontmatter. I'm having trouble with the block property in CSS. The entire navbar except for the dropdown portion is working.

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbuoL6sm/). I'm not sure how useful that will be since it has Liquid in it.

Here's a picture of what I'm looking at. I've played around with the "#navbar .ddm a" section of the CSS, so I know I'm in the right spot, but it doesn't matter if I put block. Inline works correctly. It just defaults to inline-block, even if I delete "display: "
[image]

This is the css that I think should be the culprit

```
#navbar .ddm a {
  color: green;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Is this the intended result? --> https://jsfiddle.net/kbuoL6sm/3/ (`#navbar .dropdown-menu li {
    float: none;
}`)

Comment: Yes, I'd like the dropdown to be vertical, rather than horizontal.

Edit: I'd like to avoid doing what you did (ie. stacking <li> elements) since I have a forloop to accomplish that.

Comment: Well there you go :)

Comment: I'd like to avoid doing what you did (ie. stacking <li> elements) since I have a forloop to accomplish that.

Comment: Only for demonstration

Comment: All you have to do is add the following style rule: `#navbar .dropdown-menu li { float: none; }` (declared as the last rule in the Fiddle linked, you can't miss it)

Comment: Oops! That's perfect thanks!

Comment: I've added my answer officially - explanation included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements that need to be targeted are the list items (`li`) of the dropdown menu.
You're focus was on the nested anchor tags (`a`). So you needed to be looking one level up - at the containing parent elements (`li`).

In order to achieve your intended result, you need to remove the `float` declared on *only* the dropdown list items, **e.g:**

```
#navbar .dropdown-menu li { 
float: none; 
}
```

As long as you have `float` rules declared, aligning elements with `display` rules won't be effective.

**Fiddle Demonstration**
https://jsfiddle.net/kbuoL6sm/3/ (additional styles included)